# Unable to add objects to custom list view from FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, list, listview, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Initially, after setting up custom listview, no more items are getting added i.e displayed in list view inspite of adding Object item from FirebaseMessagingService.
I have declared listView static so that Object can be added to the list from other classes or services.
Here's my code:

FirebaseMessagingService:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), remoteMessage.getData().get("transaction"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Block  b = gson.fromJson(remoteMessage.getData().get("transaction"), Block.class);
            OpenChain.arrayList.add(b);
        }
    });
}
```

ListView activity code:

```
public static ArrayList<Block> arrayList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_chain);

    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Vote Ledger");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    BlockchainAdap adap = new BlockchainAdap(this, arrayList);

    listView.setAdapter(adap);
    adap.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

**I am receiving object from cloud in json format
**Also able to add objects from within listview activity but not from FirebaseMessagingSerivce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have declared listView static so that Object can be added to the
>   list from other classes or services.

Not, a good solution, you are **leaking** arrayList here, as it wont be garbage collected when activity gets destroyed.

A better approach would be to use **LocalBroadCast** in this scenario.

Checkout the link for info

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html

Now, what you are doing wrong. You, are modifying the arraylist but you are not notifying the adapter about the same.

Try this..

```
private ArrayList<Block> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private BlockchainAdap adap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_chain);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Vote Ledger");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    adap = new BlockchainAdap(this, arrayList);

    listView.setAdapter(adap);
}

public static void updateList(Block b){
   arrayList.add(b);
   adap.swap(arrayList);
}
```

In FirebaseMessagingService

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Block  b = gson.fromJson(remoteMessage.getData().get("transaction"), Block.class);
            OpenChain.updateList(b);   
}
```

Also, expose a method in your ** BlockchainAdap** for swap.

```
class BlockchainAdap {
   ArrayList<Block> arrayList;
   BlockchainAdap(ArrayList<Block> arrayList){
     this.arrayList = arrayList;
   }

   public void swap(ArrayList<Block> arrayList){
     this.arrayList = arrayList;
     notifydatasetChanged();
   }

   // other methods

}
```

This will work, but use

- LocalBroadcastReceiver from messaging service to OpenChain activity.
- Use RecyclerView instead of ListView.